# How to create a new Google sheet for every new user by passing some user parameters?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I am trying to create a project, in which I wanted to create a google sheet for every new user a new google sheet should get generated and display data of that particular user on that newly created spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

try this script:

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
        .addItem('Create New Tabs', 'createTabs')
        .addToUi()
}

function createTabs() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    ss.getSheetByName('MASTERSHEET').getRange('A:A').getValues().filter(String)
        .forEach(function (sn) {
            if (!ss.getSheetByName(sn[0])) {
                ss.insertSheet(sn[0], ss.getSheets().length);
            }
        })
}
```

create sheet and name it **MASTERSHEET**

then put your user names in column A

go to My Menu and create sheets

[image: 0]